# Indy TCPClient and rogue byte in InputBuffer

Tags: delphi, tcp, delphi-7, indy10

I am using the following few lines of code to write and read from an external Modem/Router (aka device) via IP.

```
TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(MsgStr);
TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear; 
TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, 10, True);
```

MsgStr is a string type which contains the text that I am sending to my device.
Buffer is declared as TIdBytes.
I can confirm that IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty returns True immediately prior to calling ReadBytes.

I'm expecting the first 10 bytes received to be very specific hence from my point of view I am only interested in the first 10 bytes received after I've sent my string.

The trouble I am having is, when talking to certain devices, the first byte returned *the first time I've sent a string after establishing a connection* puts a rogue (random) byte in my Buffer output.  The subsequent bytes following are correct.

eg 10 bytes I'm expecting might be: **#6A1EF1090#3** but what I get is **.#6A1EF1090**.  in this example I have a full stop where there shouldn't be one.

If I try to send again, it works fine. (ie the 2nd Write sent after a connection has been established).  What's weird (to me) is using a Socket Sniffer doesn't show the random byte being returned.  If I create my own "server" to receive the response and send something back it works fine 100% of the time.  Other software - ie, not my software - communicates fine with the device (but of course I have no idea how they're parsing the data).

Is there anything that I'm doing incorrectly above that would cause this - bearing in mind it only occurs the first time I'm using Write after establishing a connection?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I'm using Delphi 7 and Indy 10.5.8

**UPDATE**

Ok.  After much testing and looking, I am no closer to finding this solution.  I am getting two main scenarios.  1 - First byte missing and 2 - "introduced" byte at the start of received packet.  Using TIdLogEvent and TIdLogDebug both either show the missing byte or the initial introduced byte as appropriate.  So my ReadBytes statement above is showing consistently what Indy believes is there (in my opinion).

Also, to test it further, I downloaded and installed ICS components.  Unfortunately (or fortunately depending on how you look at it) this didn't show the same issues as Indy.  This didn't show the first byte missing nor did it show an introduced byte at the beginning.  However, I have only done superficial testing, but Indy produces the behaviour "pretty much straight away" whereas ICS hasn't produced it at all yet.

If anyone is interested I can supply a small demo app illustrating the issue and IP I connect to - it's a public IP so anyone can access it.  Otherwise for now, I'll just have to work around it.  I'm reluctant to switch to ICS as ICS may work fine in this instance and given the use of this socket stuff is pretty much the whole crux of the program, it would be nasty to have to entirely replace Indy with ICS.

Comment: try sending an AnsiString(sizeof(char)=1), that might help

Comment: Where would I place that code?  FYI, I edited my question to show Delphi versions I'm using in case you thought I was using later Delphi versions which use Unicode.

Comment: you should use the tags to specify the delphi version

Comment: Did you initialize the buffer and checked if it is really the ReadBytes which adds the extra byte?

Comment: @mjn. Yep.  I initialized as in I added this line before ReadBytes: SetLength(Buffer, 10);.  Would that be sufficient?  Checking the contents of Buffer prior to ReadBytes shows (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) in the Watch.  As soon as I step over ReadBytes (which is the next line) buffer fills with (32, 6, 48, 51, 48, 49, 53, 69, 55, 69).  In this instance, 32 is the rogue byte.  6 "should" have been first.  tks

Comment: If this is an old serial port based device, then my memory tells me that you often get a duff character as the first byte on opening the port. It was the nature of the interface. If you can be sure your data starts with the #, then look for that, and ignore anything before.

Answer (score 3):

The last parameter (True)

```
TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, 10, True);
```

causes the read to **append** instead of replace the buffer content.

This requires that size and content of the buffer are set up correctly first.

If the parameter is False, the buffer content will be replaced for the given number of bytes.

Comment: unfortunately setting it to False makes no difference - if that's what you mean.  I also tried various combinations of SetLength(Buffer,10) with True/False too in case that helped which it didn't.  But given True works for every subsequent send/receive I would have been surprised (happily albeit) if that worked.  :)

Answer (score 1):

`ReadBytes()` does not inject rogue bytes into the buffer, so there are only two possibilities I can think of right now given the limited information you have provided:

1. The device really is sending an extra byte upon initial connection, like mj2008 suggested. If a packet sniffer is not detecting it, try attaching one of Indy's own `TIdLog...` components to your `TIdTCPClient`, such as `TIdLogFile` or `TIdLogEvent`, to verify what `TIdTCPClient` is actually receiving from the socket.
2. you have another thread reading from the same connection at the same time, corrupting the `InputBuffer`. Even a call to `TIdTCPClient.Connected()` will perform a read. Don't perform reads in multiple threads at the same time, if you are using the threads.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try pt 1 and see if that provides any insight and report back.